# Ruby scope and guidelines. Which is better and why?

Tags: ruby, scope, format

I had a question about scope in Ruby. I am going to paste two versions of the same script, both work but one introduces variables that work into a class above the class and the other introduces them below before the class instances and calls. I prefer to write with them above the class as It seems easier for me to track what is going to go into the class if anything. Is there a reason I can not do this?

#### Script A

```
require 'ipaddress'

puts "What class network?"
network_class = gets.chomp.to_s.downcase
puts "What is the ip?"
ip = gets.chomp.to_s.downcase
puts "How many subnets?"
subnets = gets.chomp.to_i

class TheSubNetter

  def initialize(network_class, ip, subnets)
    @network_class = network_class
    @ip = ip
    @subnets = subnets
  end

  def ip_class
    if @network_class == "c"
      IPAddress "#{@ip}/24"
    elsif @network_class == "b"
      IPAddress "#{@ip}/16"
    elsif @network_class == "a"
      IPAddress "#{@ip}/8"
    else
      "Error!"
    end
  end

  def subnet(ip)
    subnets = ip.split(@subnets)
  end

  def ranges(subnets)
    bcast = subnets.map do |i|
      i.broadcast
    end
    bcast.map do |i|
      [i.first.to_string, i.last.to_string]  
    end
  end

end

get_subd = TheSubNetter.new(network_class, ip, subnets)
address = get_subd.ip_class
subnets = get_subd.subnet(address)
ranges = get_subd.ranges(subnets)
ranges.each do |i|
  puts i[0] + "  =>  " + i[1]
end
```

#### Script B

```
require 'ipaddress'

class TheSubNetter

  def initialize(network_class, ip, subnets)
    @network_class = network_class
    @ip = ip
    @subnets = subnets
  end

  def ip_class
    if @network_class == "c"
      IPAddress "#{@ip}/24"
    elsif @network_class == "b"
      IPAddress "#{@ip}/16"
    elsif @network_class == "a"
      IPAddress "#{@ip}/8"
    else
      "Error!"
    end
  end

  def subnet(ip)
    subnets = ip.split(@subnets)
  end

  def ranges(subnets)
    bcast = subnets.map do |i|
      i.broadcast
    end
    bcast.map do |i|
      [i.first.to_string, i.last.to_string]  
    end
  end

end

puts "What class network?"
network_class = gets.chomp.to_s.downcase
puts "What is the ip?"
ip = gets.chomp.to_s.downcase
puts "How many subnets?"
subnets = gets.chomp.to_i

get_subd = TheSubNetter.new(network_class, ip, subnets)
address = get_subd.ip_class
subnets = get_subd.subnet(address)
ranges = get_subd.ranges(subnets)
ranges.each do |i|
  puts i[0] + "  =>  " + i[1]
end
```

Comment: It could be argued that the question is irrelevant since the class should be in its own, separate file. But it’s all style up to the author.

Comment: Thank you for the edit and thank you for the quick answer! I normally do separate the two, I kept them together for this since it was small and quick and was wondering if there was a S.O.P. for such small instances of files. Thank you again sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want your code to be ordered by conceptual dependency, by which I mean; "where does the information come from" and "how is the information used".

**During development**, the class contents are conceptually dependent on the first block of code - the block is the origin of the information, and the class is the usage of that information. Then, the meaning of the second block is dependent on the (presumably) constantly changing class - again, origin of the information, and use of it. So putting the class definition between the blocks makes sense *during development*.

**During production**, the meaning the of the second block *is* dependent on that first block, and the class in *entirely independent of either*, being completed: it's static now - unchanging; you know what it's doing. So, the blocks need to be together, and the class needs to be "elsewhere": origin of the information, known transformation, use of the information.

Basically, once the class is done, it's "library code", and goes where "library code" always goes: Out of sight. Top, bottom, or other file.

Comment: Thank you again! You guys have been great for clearing this up for me.